proteger celda cuando usuario la este usando
en Google Sheets como puedo hacer que cuando un usuario este ocupando una celda no pueda ser ocupada por otro usuario hasta que el primero se cambie de celda?
Es un archivo excel que estoy importando a google sheets para ser ocupado online, si no se puede em google sheets alguien lo ha logrado hacer en otra plataforma con el requisito del primer parrafo?

Hola, Anthony, bienvenido. ¿Podrías por favor decirnos qué has intentado hasta ahora para resolver el problema?

De la pregunta

en Google Sheets como puedo hacer que cuando un usuario este ocupando una celda no pueda ser ocupada por otro usuario hasta que el primero se cambie de celda?

Esto no es posible en Google Sheets porque no hay un evento "ocupando celda", lo más cercano es el activador onSelectionChange pero dado que es un activador simple no puede modificar la protección de la celda.
